# Completion of $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}),\mu_0)$

Tags: measure-theory

I know that a Dirac measure is a complete measure but I cannot find the completion of $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}),\mu_0)$ where $\mu_0$ is the Dirac measure concentrated at $0$.

Answer (score 2):

A completion is made usually by starting to add all subsets of measure $0$ sets as measurable sets.
So all subsets of $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ (which is Borel of measure $0$) are in the completion $\sigma$-algebra, and so is $\{0\}$ (Borel of measure $1$). So *all* subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ are measurable, and we use the same formula for computing the measure: $\hat{\mu}_0(A) = 1$ iff $0 \in A$, $0$ otherwise.

So the completion is simply $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}), \hat{\mu}_0)$.